# Vega-Lite + Kibana: Match unit of size to the x-axis time unit to achieve accurate timespan inbetween events

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

I'm using Elastic/Kibana to gather data and visual it, I've got a server compiling code and running tests, after each I submit a record to Elastic of when the job started, how long it took and if it was a success.. etc.

I took the bubble-plot natural disaster graph as an example with the goal to show a circle for each job that kicked off. But the size of my bubble (mapped to duration in minutes) does not match my x-axis (mapped to timestamp) and set to timeunit minutes..

am I approaching this wrong? this is my first time using vega-lite. I'm not sure if what I'm after is possible.

my current code:

```
        {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:01:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 360, "serverName": "SERV0", "taskResult": "Success"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:11:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 5, "serverName": "SERV0", "taskResult": "Failure"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:21:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 360, "serverName": "SERV0", "taskResult": "Success"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:31:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 360, "serverName": "SERV0", "taskResult": "Success"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:41:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 12, "serverName": "SERV0", "taskResult": "Failure"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:51:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 360, "serverName": "SERV0", "taskResult": "Success"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:11:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 1, "serverName": "SERV1", "taskResult": "User Abort"},
      {"timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:6:01.4327375+00:00", "timerDuration": 500, "serverName": "SERV1", "taskResult": "Success"}
    ]
  },

  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate('timeStamp')", "as": "var_time"},
    {"calculate": "'timerDuration' / 60", "as": "var_duration_min"}
  ],
  
  "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "var_time",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"grid": false, "labelAngle": 60},
      "timeUnit": "utcminutes",
      "title": null
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "serverName",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": null
    },
    "color": {
      "condition":[
          {"test": "'taskResult' == 'Success'", "value": "green"},
          {"test": "'taskResult' == 'User Abort'", "value": "white"},
          {"test": "'taskResult' == 'Script Error'", "value": "purple"}
        ],
        "value": "red"
        },
    "size": {
      "field": "var_duration_min",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "serverName", "type": "nominal", "title": "Server"},
      {"field": "taskNameShort", "type": "nominal", "title": "Task"},
      {"field": "var_time", "type": "temporal", "title": "Started At"},
      {"field": "var_duration_min", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Duration (min)"},
      {"field": "taskResult", "type": "nominal", "title": "Result"}
    ]
  }
}
```

[this is how it looks, the time filter thing from kibana also doesn't seem to work...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEcd3.png)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share dummy data.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that.. had to check documentation how to make the dummy data, I used the vega editor, but now it just shows a flat line in there... I also added a screenshot to show what it looks like in Kibana..
I'm not sure why the vega editor one is broken :(

edit: I pulled those timestamps right from the elastic indexes, so that's how it looks like when submitted.. not sure if Kibana does any parsing on that..

Answer (score 0):

I checked your vega-lite config. And noticed that the `datum` was missing in your calculate and conditions. I have updated your configuration below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": "container",
  "width": "container",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:01:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 360,
        "serverName": "SERV0",
        "taskResult": "Success"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:11:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 5,
        "serverName": "SERV0",
        "taskResult": "Failure"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:21:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 360,
        "serverName": "SERV0",
        "taskResult": "Success"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:31:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 360,
        "serverName": "SERV0",
        "taskResult": "Success"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:41:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 12,
        "serverName": "SERV0",
        "taskResult": "Failure"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:51:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 360,
        "serverName": "SERV0",
        "taskResult": "Success"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:11:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 1,
        "serverName": "SERV1",
        "taskResult": "User Abort"
      },
      {
        "timeStamp": "2021-02-24T01:6:01.4327375+00:00",
        "timerDuration": 500,
        "serverName": "SERV1",
        "taskResult": "Success"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum.timeStamp)", "as": "var_time"},
    {"calculate": "datum.timerDuration / 60", "as": "var_duration_min"}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "var_time",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {"grid": false, "labelAngle": 60},
      "timeUnit": "utcminutes",
      "title": null
    },
    "y": {"field": "serverName", "type": "ordinal", "title": null},
    "color": {
      "condition": [
        {"test": "datum.taskResult == 'Success'", "value": "green"},
        {"test": "datum.taskResult == 'User Abort'", "value": "white"},
        {"test": "datum.taskResult == 'Script Error'", "value": "purple"}
      ],
      "value": "red"
    },
    "size": {"field": "var_duration_min", "type": "quantitative"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "serverName", "type": "nominal", "title": "Server"},
      {"field": "taskNameShort", "type": "nominal", "title": "Task"},
      {"field": "var_time", "type": "temporal", "title": "Started At"},
      {
        "field": "var_duration_min",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Duration (min)"
      },
      {"field": "taskResult", "type": "nominal", "title": "Result"}
    ]
  }
}
```